# webpack plugin to replace a function with another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-plugin

I am trying to create a webpack plugin, that will parse the code for a certain function and replace it with another function, that plugin will also expose the new function as a global.

```
class someName {
  constructor(local, domain, translationFile, options) {
  }

  apply(compiler) {

    // exposing ngt function as a global
    compiler.plugin('make', function(compilation, callback) {
      var childCompiler = compilation.createChildCompiler('someNameExpose');
      childCompiler.apply(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        ngt: function(singular , plural, quantity) {
          return quantity == 1 ? singular : plural;
        }
      }));
      childCompiler.runAsChild(callback);
    });

    // searching for the getValue function
    compiler.parser.plugin(`call getValue`, function someNameHandler(expr) {

      // create a function to replace getValue with
      let results = 'ngt('+ expr.arguments  +')';
      const dep = new ConstDependency(results, expr.range);
      dep.loc = expr.loc;
      this.state.current.addDependency(dep);
      return true;
    });
  }
}

module.exports = someName;
```

**update / rephrase**

I have an issue here, when `compiler.parser.plugin('call getValue', function someNameHandler(expr) {...}` block is commented the `ngt` function exist as a global.

when its not commented, i get an error, ngt is undefined.

commented i mean `/**/`

I found a workaround for that but its far then idea. right now what I do is I export an anonymous function that does what i want.

You can see the plugin here:
[Github](https://github.com/yanivkalfa/i18n-gettext-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/index.js)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to clarify the following points? How is `reactjs` tag relevant?  Is it webpack 1 or 2? (might be obvious to an expert, but better make it explicit) Could you rephrase the last 2 sentences, with more details? (sorry, might be me, but I have trouble understanding what the problem is)

Comment: @Hugues Moreau it doesnt have direct relation to reactjs but it is used for reactjs, webpack 1. and i've updated the question with more details.

Comment: why not write/use a babel plugin for this? its much easier and babel is after all a transpiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method based on environment. Let's say you have a method

```
function a(){
  //original defination
}
```

Now based on the environment, if it's a production you could do something like this

```
if (environment.production) {
   function a(){
     //overridden defination
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the webpack-merge plugin, it's very useful to do exactly what do you want.

https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge

Comment: How is this useful? I went to the link and it's for merging objects. The OP wants to replace a function call which is different. Can you share a snippet to show how OP can achieve the purpose?